# Построение запросов в Laravel 7.3

Tags: php, laravel

Не могу разобраться в построении запроса в Laravel 7.3 Eloquent ORM. Собственно выполняю обучающее задание, нужно из двух таблиц Users и Tasks. Вывести все задачи пользователя.

```
use App\User;
use App\Task;

protected $tasks;

public function forUser(User $user)
    {

        return Task::addSelect([
            'name' => User::select('name')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
        ])->get();

    }
```

Я правильно понимаю? Я обращаюсь к модели Task, которая связана с БД и моделью Users(отношение один ко многим) и вытаскиваю задачи пользователя. Причем если только пользователь авторезирован. Не совсем понимаю логику простроения запросов.

Comment: Больше похоже на то, что вы тащите задания всех пользователей

Answer (score 1):

1. у вас в таблице tascs должно быть поле user_id.
2. в модели User напишите метод, который определит отношение один ко многим:

   public function tasks(){
      return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
   }
3. Получить все таски юзера теперь можно:
   $user_tasks = $user->tasks;
4. Либо без определения отношений (не райт вей))) 
       $tasks = Task::where('user_id', $user['id'])
                     ->get();
   как-то так..
   Подробнее [Здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)